# Issue an HTTP GET from REPL in Racket

Tags: http, scheme, racket, read-eval-print-loop

I feel like I'm missing something, but after perusing the docs for net/url and poking around in general, I was unable to figure out a way to issue a GET request from the interactive prompt. Basically, I want to imitate my python workflow for poking around a website:

```
response = urlopen("http://www.someurl.com")
```

is this feasible in Racket?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [`call/input-url`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/url.html#%28def._%28%28lib._net%2Furl..rkt%29._call%2Finput-url%29%29) has a few advantages:

- You don't need to close the port yourself.
- The port is closed even if there's an exception.
- Its third argument is `(input-port? -> any/c)` -- that is, a function that takes an `input-port` and returns anything. In addition to a function you write yourself, this could be an already-defined function like `port->string`, `read-html-as-xml`, and so on.

For example:

```
(call/input-url (string->url "http://www.google.com/")
                get-pure-port
                port->string)
```

Note: As I was typing this answer, I notice that Óscar edited his to do redirects. My similar edit would be:

```
(call/input-url (string->url "http://www.google.com/")
                (curry get-pure-port #:redirections 4)
                port->string)
```

Of course, either way is still fairly verbose to type frequently at the REPL. So Óscar's suggestion to define your own `url-open` function is a good one. Implementing it using `call/input-url` would be preferable, I think.

Comment: Is there any way to extract the status code other than parsing the headers "by hand"?  I'm surprised that I could not find any helper function to do that, either in racket proper, or in your http library.

Comment: Sorry I didn't even notice your comment until now! My http lib has functions to do this: https://github.com/greghendershott/http/blob/master/http/head.rkt#L22-L45

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
(require net/url)

(define input (get-pure-port (string->url "http://www.someurl.com")))
(define response (port->string input))
(close-input-port input)
```

Now the `response` variable will contain the http response from the server. Even better, pack the above in a procedure, also notice that I added a maximum number of redirections allowed:

```
(define (urlopen url)
  (let* ((input (get-pure-port (string->url url) #:redirections 5))
         (response (port->string input)))
    (close-input-port input)
    response))

(urlopen "http://www.someurl.com") ; this will return the response
```

**EDIT:**

Following @GregHendershott's excellent advice (see his answer for details), here's another, more robust way to implement the desired functionality:

```
(define (urlopen url)
  (call/input-url
   (string->url url)
   (curry get-pure-port #:redirections 5)
   port->string))
```